# Redirect from existent route to a new one

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, symfony-2.7, symfony-routing

I'm trying to redirect if a user is not logged in (works with FOSUser and SonataAdmin) and calls either `http://domain.com/app_dev.php` (dev) or `http://domain.com` (prod) then I want in both cases redirect to `/login` so I wrote this config at `app/routing.yml`:

```
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /login
        permanent: true
```

That works but I have a problem since I have this in a controller:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return array
 * @Route("/", name="brand")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    ....
}
```

Then when I try to call `brand` route as per example using a link like: `http://domain.com/app_dev.php/?email=7x-xRFClkjw` (dev) or `http://domain.com/?email=7x-xRFClkjw` (prod) I got redirected to `/login`. My best idea is to change my code into this:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return array
 * @Route("/bp", name="brand")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    ....
}
```

And then [redirect using a route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html#redirecting-using-a-route) to the new `/bp` instead to `/` for that function (this is mainly because users already has a tons of emails that had links as the previously shared and I can't change that). But I've not idea in how to write this rule in `routing.yml` because if I wrote this:

```
bp:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: brand
        permanent: true
```

I will end up with a redirect loop. I could change also how default route to `/login` is setup I just can't find the right documentation. The big idea behind this post is to setup default route for `/`. Can any give me some help on this?

As extra info this is part of my `security.yml` file:

```
firewalls:
    ...

    admin_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            # the user is redirected here when they need to log in
            login_path: /login

            # submit the login form here
            check_path: /login_check

            # login success redirecting options (read further below)
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
            target_path_parameter: _target_path
            use_referer: false
            failure_path: /admin/dashboard
            failure_forward: false
        logout:
            path:   /logout
```

**UPDATE**

Actually the code from @emmanuel-hdz-díaz give me another idea and I don't need to create a kernel listener or add to much code, simple by doing this at my controller:

```
if ($request->query->get('email')) {
    ...
} else {
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sonata_user_admin_security_login'));
}
```

I was able to redirect the user to the `/login` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw a special exception, catch it in the kernel.request event, redirect from there.
You have to create a custom exception that you can store your route in.e.g:

```
class RouteException extends \Exception{
    protected $route;

     public function __construct($route){
         $this->route = $route;
    }

    public function getRoute() { return $this->route; }
}
```

Now create a listener that will generate a `RedirectResponse` when it detects this exception, e.g:

```
class RedirectExceptionListener{
  protected $router;

  public function __construct(RouterInterface $router){
    $this->router;
  }

  public function onException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event){

    $e = $event->getException();

    if($e instanceof RouteException){

      $url = $this->router->generate($e->getRoute());

      $event->setResponse(
        new RedirectResponse($url);
      );
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
# the service definition
your_listener:
    class: RedirectExceptionListener
    arguments:
        - @router
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

**Note**: you have to `use` the namespaces for the used classes.
This is basically what you can do to redirect from anywhere in your application, although it does seem like a smelly use of exceptions, so create a service `Redirecter` with a method `redirect($route)` that throws the exception for you, so the calling service will not know how the redirection is being done.The `Redirecter` can throw the exception or do anything required to redirect to the given route.
For more info on event listeners see [Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html).

**Update**: This is exactly how symfony redirects you to your `login_path` when you're not authenticated, see [ExceptionListener](https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php)

Comment: Excellent, I almost get it all but where I do set the route? I mean I can see the listener is redirecting but where to?

Comment: You set the route in the exception, see the constructor of the exception, that's where you pass the route.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand, but you want to restrict access to whole site? In that case just simply change you security setting, never add redirect to login, because it always redirect to login even if use is logged in. Here is simple configuration example:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Nope, you didn't understand me at all. Access is restricted, if any tries `/` URL meaning for example `http://domain.com/app_dev.php` (for dev) or `http://domain.com` (for prod) then I should be able to redirect to `/login`. Right now I have a route on code overlapping that `/` as you can see on the main post and I explain there my idea. I need some others since I'm not able to fix this yet

Comment: In comment above you said: "I need the same redirect behavior all over the app" - this exactly doing that, redirect user to login page if user is not logged.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your controller inside yourAction():

//

```
$usr = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

if( $usr == 'anon.' )
{
return $this->redirect($this>generateUrl('sonata_user_admin_security_login'));
}
```

//

Comment: That will works for just that controller and I don't want that I need the same redirect behavior all over the app

Comment: Throw a special exception, catch it in the `kernel.request` event, redirect from there.

Comment: @user2268997 can you provide a answer with an example illustrating that?